# Sum a list of objects based on BigDecimal field in single line

Tags: java, java-stream

Suppose we have:

```
class Foo {
   public BigDecimal field;
}
```

and that we have a list of `Foo` instances, i.e. `List<Foo> list`.

How can we calculate the sum of the values of the `field` from the objects in the list **in a single line**?

I found examples of similar cases using streams but they handle simpler cases and do not work for this; such as calculating for `List<Integer>` or when the `field` is something easily "summable" (int, Integer...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.stream().map(foo -> foo.field).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a, b) -> a.add(b));
```

Comment: doesnt work, you cannnot add `Foo` objects

Comment: `.map(Foo::getField).reduce(BigDecial::add).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO)`, but this was asked _so many_ times already.

Comment: @Eugene `Foo` has no "getField" method

Comment: @Caner how do you access `field` then?

Comment: it's a public field

Comment: @Caner the answer of Horatiu Jeflea should work. Are you sure you copied it right?

Comment: the answer got an update...now it works